# Firestore REST API make authenticated request with http-client

Tags: rest, authentication, google-cloud-firestore

I want to get data from a firestore via the REST API. I'm using an HTTP-Client (Webstorm) and do the following.

First I authenticate with Google which works fine and does return a token:

```
POST https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=<firebase-api-key>
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "email": "some@email.com",
  "password": "notthispassword"
}
```

But then, trying to get data from the firestore (not realtime-db) like this

```
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectId>/databases/(default)/documents/<collection>
Accept: application/json
Authorization: Bearer <token from auth response>
```

it keeps telling me:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
    }
}
```

These are my firestore security rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

I would be happy if somebody could tell me where I am going wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first part of the solution was to read the response carefully. It containes the following link https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.

Then I had to understand that if you are using the google-identitiy-toolkit you kind of left the firebase-realm and **must append the api-key generated in the GC-console** (not the firebase-key!) (https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials) to the URL used to fetch the data like this:

```
GET https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/<projectId>/databases/(default)/documents/<collection>?key=<google-cloud-api-key>
Accept: application/json 
Authorization: Bearer <token from auth response>
```